# Bottom Navigation Bar in linerylayout does not work

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to make a bottom navigation menu, from how I wrote in the code I only did it that it doesn't appear below. I should put it in this chat app of mine that I am doing so that it always appears after the user has logged in. Is there something I did wrong? Thanks

ChatFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    usersList = new Stack<>();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
        Query reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).orderByChild("time");
        // Get every user from chatlist reference
        reference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                usersList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Chatlist chatlist = snapshot.getValue(Chatlist.class);
                    usersList.push(chatlist);
                }
                Collections.reverse(usersList);
                chatList();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String mtoken = task.getResult();
                updateToken(mtoken);
                Log.d("TAG", mtoken); //Check the generated token.
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
    });

    registerForContextMenu(recyclerView);

    return view;
}
```

Chat Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Fragments.ChatsFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It because of your parent group LinearLayout

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">



<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
/>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/toolbarDark"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MenuStyle">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"/>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Inside res folder, create a folder called nav

inside the nav create mobile_navigation.xml and add

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <navigation 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
   app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:name="ChatFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/chat_home" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:name="DashboardFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:name="NotificationsFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_notifications"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" />
```

inside MainActivity class or whatever your dashboard class is, add

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
 setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new 
   AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, 
   R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
    NavController navController = 
    Navigation.findNavController(this, 
    R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, 
   navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, 
   navController);
    }

  }
```

chat fragment

```
package com.example

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment


 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;

 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
 import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

 import com.example.myapplication.R;

  public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle 
      savedInstanceState) {
     View  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, 
  container, false);

       return view.getRootView();
    }
 }
```

fragment_chat.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_notifications"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

forum fragment

```
 package com.example

 import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;

 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
 import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

 import com.example.myapplication.R;

 public class ForumFragment extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle 
   savedInstanceState) {
     View  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, 
  container, false);

      return view.getRootView();
    }
 }
```

Home fragment

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;

 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
 import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

 import com.example.myapplication.R;

 public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle 
    savedInstanceState) {
        View  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, 
    container, false);

     return view.getRootView();
 }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243981/discussion-on-answer-by-muraino-bottom-navigation-bar-in-linerylayout-does-not-w).